# How to dispatch message from ActionController in websocket-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

I'm developing websocket server with Rails 4 and [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) gem.

I'm thinking send a message as http POST message (because it's convenient to customize headers or so).

I'd like to dispatch websocket message from my controller, but I may not use `WebsocketRails::BaseController.send_message`. How can I do this or something wrong?

here's code:

```
# message_controller.rb

# This controller doesn't inherit from WebsocketRails::BaseController
class MessageController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    # do something with params and models
    Message.create params

    # then, I want to dispatch message here!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer by myself, just in the readme.

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails

> Broadcast to the channel from anywhere inside your Rails application.
>   An existing controller, a model, a background job, or a new
>   WebsocketRails controller.

```
latest_post = Post.latest
WebsocketRails[:posts].trigger 'new', latest_post
```